# Why is the texmaker interface grey and 90's?

Tags: texmaker, ide

I just moved from ubuntu 16.04 to windows 10 and installed texmaker, but it has this awfull looking grey IDE, which surprisingly is also displayed on the official website. This is what I want

[image]

This is dracula's dreary castle that I have

[image]

Is there any way to change? I've tried to look af this configure texmaker with "dark theme" and "default theme". I don't see a difference, it's all fifty shades of miserable grey.

Thanks :)

Comment: The look you are complaining about has been introduced in the new version (v5), because the other look seemed quite outdated to the developers. And as far as my memory goes back I haven't had these Qt surfaces in the 90s. Even on Linux the new versions ship with the new layout.

Comment: mm thanks, I feared this. Taste I guess can't be nailed down, but grey and grey? Bold.

Comment: You could try if there are [other editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) with a better look.

Comment: I'm from the future, where I finally got a new laptop and had to download a new version of Texmaker. I came here looking for a solution; I guess I won't find one. :(